# Keep file encoding in eclipse for each file (different encodings for different files)

Tags: eclipse, git, encoding

I'm working with a git repository where some of the files are encoded in latin-1 and some of them in utf-8. I'm using Eclipse CDT to work with them, and it's configured to use UTF-8 as default encoding.

The thing is, when I open latin-1 encoded files, some of the characters are not shown properly , and despite I've just tried also the Luna version, which came out 2 days ago, the problem persists (It's supposed that latin-1 and latin-2 are supported now, according to the [review information](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/eclipse/releases/4.4.0/review)).

Furthermore, and here comes the real trouble, when I modify and save latin-1 encoded files, they are being saved as UTF-8 (as configured in Eclipse), so if I push these changes to the repository, quite a lot of conflicts will emerge, messing up the entire commit.

Is there some way of telling Eclipse to keep the original encoding for each file?

Thank you.

Comment: You can set the encoding for individual files on `Properties > Resource` but you will have to do this for each file manually.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that before, but it begins to feel messy when handling many files.

Comment: The problem is, that the encoding must be guessed. There is no way to know if a file is encoded in Latin-1, Latin-2, Latin-3, Latin-4, Latin-5, ... Latin-10. You have to specify it manually.

Comment: @ceving : `file myfile.cpp` gives/guesses the encoding (Linux/GitBash), so maybe Eclipse could use this information...